# Why it sends multiple request, when I call it only once?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

My project were working fine. I just found out in console network that one of my `GET` request is sending twice, even I just send it once. [See network console](https://ibb.co/GCtbp1q)

If I comment the the whole code of `created` function, all `GET` request would no longer load/exist in the console network. (see code below)

I want to know what causes this, and how should I fix this?

---

Here is the **Component.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
    created: async function() {
        await this.$store.dispatch('file/all');
    },
};
</script>
```

And the vuex module **post.js**'s action:

```
const actions = {
    all({commit}, data) {
        return axios.get(`files`)
            .then(response => {
                commit('setData', response);
            });
    },
}
```

Comment: I suspect you somehow created 2 `Components` instances. Look at all places where you use it in other components' templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of searching, I found out that the `key` that is assigned to the **Component** caused the problem.

When the `key` is modified the `GET` request will send again. This the reason why it sends twice. Special thanks to [@Anatoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376618/anatoly) for giving me the hint.

---

Below is the usage codes:

```
<template>
    <Component :key="componentKey" @edit="dataIsChanged"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: { Component },

    data: () => ({
        componentKey: 0,
    }),
    
    methods: {
        dataIsChanged: function() {
            this.componentKey = Math.random();
        }
    }
};
</script>
```